# Android Studio not deploying changes

Tags: android, android-studio, android-recyclerview

From one moment to another any change I do on the app is not reflected. I checked out the Logcat tab and it's show me a log I put time ago. Recyclerview it's not working either right now. I tried to clean and rebuild the project but seems doesn't work.

[image]

Comment: Did it work before? Where is the rest of your code?

Answer (score 0):

the problem was I tried to cast JSONArray to List on my POJO Class.

```
// Constructor
    public IndicatorDetails(JSONObject jo) throws JSONException {
        this.version = jo.getString(JSON_VERSION);
        this.autor = jo.getString(JSON_AUTOR);
        this.codigo = jo.getString(JSON_CODIGO);
        this.nombre = jo.getString(JSON_NOMBRE);
        this.unidad_medida = jo.getString(JSON_UNIDAD_MEDIDA);
        // right here
        this.serie = (List) jo.getJSONArray(JSON_SERIE);
    }
```

So I removed that line and It works.